# Mackeys formula

Tags: representation-theory

I have been recently reading about Mackey's formula for normal subgroups and I have the following question. Let $H$ be a finite index normal subgroup of $G$ and $V$ a representation of $H$ with character $\chi_V$. Then the character of $coInd^G_H V$ is given by

$$\chi_{coInd^G_H V} = \begin{cases} \sum_{gH \in G/H} \chi_V (g h g^{-1}), \quad h \in H \\ 0, \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

As $\chi_V$ is a class function would it not be easier to write it as:

$$\chi_{coInd^G_H V} = \begin{cases} [G:H] \ \chi_V (g h g^{-1}), \quad h \in H \\ 0, \qquad \quad \qquad \qquad \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: I have found counter-examples where this is not true, eg. $C_n \lhd D_{2n}$. But I do not see why is it wrong in rewritten the formula in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ghg^{-1}$ is in the same conjugate class as $h$ in $G,$ but not necessarily in the same conjugate class in $H.$ So there might not be an $h_1\in H$ such that $ghg^{-1}=h_1hh_1^{-1}.$

But $\chi_V$ is only constant on classes in $H.$

For example, in $C_n,$ each element is in its own class, since $C_n$ is commutative. But a rotation clockwise by one step, when conjugated by a reflection in $D_{2n},$ becomes a rotation counter-clockwise by one step.